# how to append String in Array in incremental order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have some api call which returns some values and store it into Array while receiving i may get repeated values from the server which i suppose not to append when its already in Array and insert new Values,

here my sample codes :

```
-(void)getIdValue:(NSString*)getIdVal {

getTagIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

BOOL isTheObjectThere = [getTagIdList containsObject: getIdVal];

NSLog(isTheObjectThere ? @"Yes" : @"No");

if (isTheObjectThere == NO){
    [getTagIdList addObject:getIdVal];
    NSLog(@"getTagIdList -->%@",getTagIdList);

} if (isTheObjectThere == YES){
    return;
}

}
```

I want all the new data should be Stored in getTagIdList but i am getting only one record is storing

Comment: You need to check how this method: getIdValue is getting called and how many times it's called.

Comment: In this code, the array is always empty so `isTheObjectThere` will always be false and the array will always end with 1 value. If you want all of the values to be in the same array then you need to use an array that is not created for each `getIdVal`.

Answer (score 2):

You are initialising the array within the method which is wrong. You should not be initiating the array where you try to store data.(which will remove all the old data stored in previous calls)

Comment: I think you got your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger count=[ArrayData count];

for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
NSString *StringValue= ArrayData[i];

 BOOL contains = [getTagIdList containsObject: StringValue];
    if (contains==YES) {
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }
    else{
   [getTagIdList addObject: StringValue];
 }
  }
```

Here "ArrayData" is a json responce. getTagIdList is saving the string values.Try it i think this one is work.

Answer (score 0):

From jegadeesh answer i updated your code

```
getTagIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

-(void)getIdValue:(NSString*)getIdVal {


BOOL isTheObjectThere = [getTagIdList containsObject: getIdVal];

NSLog(isTheObjectThere ? @"Yes" : @"No");

if (isTheObjectThere == NO){
    [getTagIdList addObject:getIdVal];
    NSLog(@"getTagIdList -->%@",getTagIdList);

} if (isTheObjectThere == YES){
    return;
}

}
```